# Subsetting Data into Different DataFrames via a Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset

I am looking to subset variables from several data frames in a loop, saving the data frame as the same name from before it was subset. The names follow the following structure: rx.2003, rx.2004, rx.2005, etc.

I am having difficulty finding a solution to get the data to subset properly in a loop. The code below produces the following error:

`Error in ... target of assignment expands to non-language object`

`for (i in 2003:2015){
eval(parse(text = paste0('rx.', i))) <- subset(eval(parse(text = paste0('rx.', i))), select=c(ID, Drug, Year))
}`

I know this error indicates that R thinks I am asking it to subset the **text** "rx.2003", but I am trying to figure out how to indicate R to subset the dataframe itself.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `subset(get(paste0('rx.', i)), ...)`? Also, if instead of a `for` loop you use `lapply` the results will be members of a list, not wandering around the `globalenv`. You can then `names(df_list) <- paste0("rx.", 2003:2015)`.

Comment: Using `subset(get(paste0('rx.', i)), ...)` to subset works, however, the assignment is still causing trouble. Having `get(paste0('rx.', i)) <- ` as the assignment still produces the same non-language error as above. This is a rather long loop I have (with many other components), so I would rather not use lapply if I can avoid it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. For the assignment you will need, well, `assign(paste0('rx.', i), subset(...))`. Maybe you want to avoid so many calls to `paste0` and make a vector of df names first, then use that vector whenever you need it.

Comment: Put all dataframes into a list, then work with `lapply` function, avoid using `get/parse/eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try

```
 for(i in 2003:2015)
 { 
  DF <- get(paste0("rx.",i))
  assign(paste0("rx.",i),subset(DF,select = c("ID", "Drug", "Year")
 }
```

Hope this helps